# Progress Dialogue Is Not Showing

Tags: android

I have a Listview which contains data from Firebase. It takes time to fetch the data, so i added a progress dialogue, but it doesn't show up.

```
 listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        random=new Random();
        uid=new ArrayList<>();
        name=new ArrayList<>();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        databaseReference.child("AdminList").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        progressDialog.show();
                        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            if (data.getKey().equals("check")) ;
                            else {
                                uid.add(data.child("uid").getValue().toString());
                                name.add(data.child("Aname").getValue().toString());
                            }
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    }



            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: show your layout as well.

Comment: I guess it shows and dismisses quickly. Without even you noticing it?

Comment: Yes, Call `progressDialog.show();` before this line & test `databaseReference.child("AdminList")`.

Comment: I called it before that line ..it just showed then gone